# Half-SAT/ Half-Satisfiability

Tags: discrete-optimization, satisfiability

Is the following satisfiability problem hard?

Given a set of clauses over boolean variables in conjunctive normal form, decide whether there is an assignment of truth values to the variables that satisfies at least **half of the clauses**.

I looked it up for a while and the only related research I could find is on approximating MAXSAT, which probably is not quite the same thing.

Results for any constant $c\in (0,1)$ instead of $\frac 1 2$ would be interesting as well.

Comment: I may be remembering wrong, but I think the problem is in $P$ for every $c<\frac78$, by the Karloff-Zwick algorithm?

Comment: @MJD I don't think that an 7/8-approximation algorithm can distinguish between an input, where an exact MAXSAT algorithm would output 1/2 + $\epsilon$ from one that yields output 1/2 - $\epsilon$. So I don't think this algorithm works.

Comment: If $t$ is the assignment of true to all literals, and $f$ is the assignment of false to all literals, then each "or" clause is satisfied by at least one of $t$ and $f$, therefore at least one of $t$ and $f$ satisfies at least half the clauses.

Comment: The proof of Karloff-Zwick shows that there _must_ exist at least one assignment satisfying at least $\frac78$ of the clauses.  See http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/lieber/courses/algorithms/cs4800/f10/lectures/lec22-3SAT-Johnson.pdf for example.

Comment: Not exactly the same thing, but possibly interesting anyway: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/128501/how-many-clauses-are-required-for-sat-to-be-np-hard-in-cnf-formulas

Comment: @Robert Israel: So this is the kind of easy argument I kind of feared exists, that I just didn't get to at the moment. Still I think the generalization to any $c$ is interesting.

Answer (score 2):

First note that your question is not quite right.  You asked:

> Given … decide whether …

and of course the *decision* problem is straightforward: just try every possible assignment.  I assume that you meant to say “decide in polynomial time”.

---

The Karloff-Zwick algorithm shows that for *any* instance of 3SAT, there is an assignment that satisfies at least $\frac78$ of the clauses.

Karloff-Zwick says: assign the values at random.  Then each one of the $n$ causes is satisfied with probability $\frac 78$.

By linearity of expectation, the expected number of satisfied clauses $\frac78n$.

Since the *expected* number of satisfied clauses is $\frac78n$, then, by the pigeonhole principle, there must be an assignment that satisfies at least $\frac78n$ clauses.

So, when $c\le \frac78$, the problem is not only in $P$, but is trivial, because the answer is always “yes”.

Aaronson (reference below) says “A deterministic polynomial-time algorithm that's *guaranteed* to satisfy at least $\frac78$ of the clauses requires only a little more work.”

---

In contrast, for $c>\frac78$, there is probably not any corresponding algorithm, because of this theorem of Håstad:

> Suppose there exists a polynomial-time algorithm that, given as input a satisfiable 3-SAT instance, outputs an assignment that satisfies at least a $\frac78 +\epsilon$ fraction of the clauses, for some positive constant $\epsilon$.  Then $P=NP$.

This is Håstad, J. 2001 “[Some optimal inapproximability results](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Egasarch/BLOGPAPERS/max3satl.pdf)” *Journal of the ACM*, **48** pp 798–859.

See also Aaronson, Scott “[$P{\stackrel?=}NP$](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/pnp.pdf)” p 25.

Comment: This would be for a version of $3$-SAT where each clause has exactly $3$ distinct literals.  Otherwise $(x \vee x \vee x) \wedge (\neg x \vee \neg x \vee \neg x)$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: True, but we can either eliminate those clauses or decide the problem in polynomial time, using Davis-Putnam or something like that, so it's doesn't affect the result significantly.

Comment: As for your first paragraph, your interpretation here is correct, I meant to ask, whether this is NP-hard. Still, I also find the question whether it is utterly trivial (as Robert Israel showed for $c\leq \frac 1 2$ or not interesting as well, maybe I should have just asked about time complexity in specific, but I am unsure, whether editing the question after you answered it is the right move.

Comment: As for the rest of your post, thank you very much, I think this pretty much wraps up the 3SAT case. Now I know we can change a SAT instance into a equisatisfiable 3SAT instance but the maximum number of satisfied clauses can change, if I am not mistaken. Could you elaborate on how to modify a MAXSAT instance into a MAX3SAT instance yielding the same constant $c$? I also think modifications of the sort of Davis-Putnam run into a similar problem. Additionally, applying Davis-Putnam may blow up the size of the input exponentially, rendering any non-trivial algorithm after it inefficient.

Comment: It completely escaped me that you were asking about MAX-SAT and not MAX-3-SAT, sorry.  I have a few replies to make but probably the most useful one is that [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_satisfiability_problem#Approximation_algorithms) explicitly gives several approximation algorithms that you appear not to be aware of.  For example, there is an algorithm that is guaranteed to find an assignment satisfying $\frac34$ of the clauses, full stop. So perhaps you could start there, and then follow up with the cited reference (Vazirani _Approximation Algorithms_).